# asp.net master page pass data for all actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, action-filter

master page contains form , the form inside contains dropdownlist, when any option is selected the form is submited.
please say elegant way keeping mvc pattern for each action method I can get dropdown selected value

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think that this would be a problem, as you can have multiple forms on a page. Just put a form on your masterpage. Something like this

Master.cshtml

```
@Html.BeginForm("{Action}", "{Controller}")
{
    <select id="formList" name="formList">
        // your options go here
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}

@RenderBody
```

Where {Action} and {Controller} is obviously the controller you want to handle the processing when the user selects something from the dropdown list. And then your view would have it's own form.

SomeView.cshtml (POST example shown)

```
@{
    Layout = "pathTo/Master.cshtml";
}

@Html.BeginForm()
{
    // define your view
}
```

Your html would render two different forms posting to two different actions.

Answer (score 0):

Following step is one possible solution.

1. You have dropdown in master page when you change that you have to store that value in Cookie
2. Create Value Provide as per following link
   http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/03/07/aspnet-mvc-working-smart-with-cookies-custom-valueprovider
3. Than use that in every action by name as per example in above link.

It works for me.